# Create notification from non-activity class

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to create notification from non-activity class? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass the context in to the class and then create it normally

Comment: i don't know how you mean it, could you post some snippet? thanks

Comment: @Hmyzak sorry next time i will try to show example :( hope you fine

Answer (score 2):

```
class A extends Activity{
//required stuff go here
new B().createDialog(A.this);


}
```

other class

```
class B{

public void createDialog(Context context){
//create your dialog or notification here
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As subspider said above, pass the context into the class and you'll be fine:

```
public class DoSomethingClass {

    //Here's a context
    private Context _CONTEXT;

    //Construct that sets the context
    public DoSomethingClass(Context c) {
        this._CONTEXT = c;
    }

    public void createNotification() {

       /* 
           Create the notification as usual, just make sure you alter the following lines:

           Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
           Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

           ^Make sure you alter this into this._CONTEXT above
       */
    }
}
```